# Formula in Excel graph

Tags: excel, graph

I am creating a line graph in Excel 2007. What I would like to achieve is to specify a formula in the chart data range.

What I have now in the chart data range is:

```
=SHEET1!$B$1:$W$1;SHEET1!$B$7:$W$7
```

This simply creates a line graph using the `B1,C1,D1,...` and `B7,C7,D7...` values.

However, I would like to manipulate the second data `($B$7:$W$7)` by dividing it another row and then use the result in the graph. So the result should be something like:

`=SHEET1!$B$1:$W$1;SHEET1!($B$7:$W$7/$B$8:$W$8)`

This formula returns error. I need B7 divided by B8, then C7 divided by C8 and so on. And the calculated result should be used in the graph.

I know that I can easily create a new row for my calculation and create a graph with it. But I was wondering if that calculation can be made on the fly when creating the graph.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It belongs on Super User not Stack Overflow

Comment: should be closed, OP opened it in SU http://superuser.com/questions/430052/formula-in-excel-graph

Answer (score 0):

Use another column in the worksheet to calculate the values you want to plot. Excel is great at plotting worksheet data. It cannot plot formulas other than links. While you could define named ranges (named formulas), these are tricky to write and tricky to debug and maintain.